# stuck in : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my first project and my first post.
I'm creating a betting website to use between friends and I'm stuck with this error : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I guess its something small to make its work again?

Any sugestions?

```
router.post("/bets", function(req, res){
    var betHome = req.body.betHome;
    var betAway = req.body.betAway;
    var matchid= "5e84bd729511b98c34101a9e"
    var author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    }
    var newBet = {bet:[betHome,betAway],author:author, matchid:matchid}
    Bet.create(newBet, function (err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            Match.betsList.push(newBet)
           res.redirect("/bets");
           console.log(newBet)

        }
        })
})

module.exports = router;
```

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH3uI.png)

Comment: `Match.betsList` is `undefined`

Comment: how to define it? I refere to it on top to the model

var express = require("express");
var router  = express.Router();
var Match = require("../models/match");
var Bet = require("../models/bet");

Comment: Share with us what's in the ../models/match file, in particular the `betsList`

Comment: You can't push directly into Model. First, create an object then push. new Match({})

Comment: pictures of models did't went true sorry. and thanks for all the answers. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH3uI.png

Comment: I added

 var betslist={id:"5e85781d21ad853718548293"}
    
    var newMatch = {home: home, away: away, result:[resultHome,resultAway], betslist:betslist }

Answer (score 0):

You can't push in Model directly first create an object of Match Model then push.

```
   router.post("/bets", function(req, res){
    var betHome = req.body.betHome;
    var betAway = req.body.betAway;
    var matchid= "5e84bd729511b98c34101a9e"
    var author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    }
    var newBet = {bet:[betHome,betAway],author:author, matchid:matchid}
    Bet.create(newBet, function (err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
         var match = new Match({});  // new Schema
            match.betsList.push(newlyCreated._id)
           res.redirect("/bets");
           console.log(newBet)

        }
        })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thx, looks good. seemsto work. Have to check in detail. THank uyou so much.

Comment: newBet._id is undefined I guess I have to save it first but if I try newBet.save() or Bet.save(newBet) I get Bet.save() is not a function

Comment: I thin it should be newlyCreated._id